# Fill remaining space with a view that has aspect ratio in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have two views (viewA, viewB) in vertical chain. aspect ratio of viewA should always be 1:1, while height of viewB is dynamic (it may be 400dp, may be 700dp)

Expected results:
Width viewA should be reduced (keeping the aspect ratio) when the height of viewB is too big to fit two views in screen.

Actual result:
Width of viewA always matches parent and views leave bounds of screen if height of viewB is too big.

NOTE: It is desired to use ConstantsLayout and don't have nested viewgroups.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/viewA"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewB"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="700dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewA"/>
```

Comment: You're forcing height of viewB to 700, how can you think that will change?

Comment: It's a sample to illustrate  the problem. Imagine there is textview instead with height wrap_content and text is dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the dimension ratio of the top view to the following:

```
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
```

Now, when the bottom view height changes, the top will track as you want while maintaining the 1:1 ratio. I added color to better see the views in the layout.

*Bottom view at 700dp*

[image]

*Bottom view at 500dp*

[image]

*Bottom view at 200dp*

[image]

Comment: My use case was a single view at the bottom of a ConstraintLayout. The view had to fill a third of the parent layout. So `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` plus `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,2:1"` ended up as the solution. Thanks for the hint.